# Using sed/awk to append one line to another

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

To simplify what I want, I have this:

```
Group name="Group1"
Device name="G1_Device1" host="G1_host1"
Device name="G2_Device2" host="G1_host2"
Group name="Group2"
Device name="G2_Device1" host="G2_host1"
Group name="Group3"
Device name="G3_Device1" host="G3_Host1"
Device name="G3_Device2" host="G3_host2"
Device name="G3_Device3" host="G3_host3"
Device name="G3_Device4" host="G3_host4"
```

And I need this (check the group name):

```
Group name="Group1" Device name="G1_Device1" host="G1_host1"
Group name="Group1" Device name="G2_Device2" host="G1_host2"
Group name="Group2" Device name="G2_Device1" host="G2_host1"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device1" host="G3_Host1"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device2" host="G3_host2"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device3" host="G3_host3"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device4" host="G3_host4"
```

Is there any way to do that with sed and/or awk?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add your attempt to solve this. Based on the tags you've included, I'd expect to see some code in bash, awk and sed in your question. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51179303/edit) to add the missing parts.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why experimented people give answer to questions without research/effort to solve the problem. Sometime, they get upvote for three or more for a basic sed or awk. very strange ???

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Again bulk down vote happened to all the posts:(  @Ed Morton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$1=="Group"{save=$0}; $1=="Device"{print save,$0}' file
```

Output:

```
Group name="Group1" Device name="G1_Device1" host="G1_host1"
Group name="Group1" Device name="G2_Device2" host="G1_host2"
Group name="Group2" Device name="G2_Device1" host="G2_host1"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device1" host="G3_Host1"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device2" host="G3_host2"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device3" host="G3_host3"
Group name="Group3" Device name="G3_Device4" host="G3_host4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples then following may help you here.

```
awk '/^Group name/{value=$0;next} {print value,$0}' Input_file
```

So here I am not doing the check if a line is having string `device` or not, if your Input_file may have many other lines after `Group` then we may have to put check like @Cyrus's solution does.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -E '/^Group/{h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' infile
```

Explained:

```
/^Group/ {              # If the line starts with "Group"...
    h                   # copy pattern space to hold space
    d                   # Delete pattern space, start new cycle
}
G                       # Append hold space to pattern space (inserts newline)
s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/     # Swap two lines in pattern space
```

The `-E` option (`-r` for some older seds) is just convenience; otherwise, the capture groups need escaping, as in `\(.*\)`.